# Cannot run xamarin project on any devices

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-emulator

I have been using xamarin over the past month, exclusively in the office on a mac. Now I want to pull some code down and fiddle out of the office, I use a windows machine at home. I've pulled down my code & opened sample projects but I have absolutely no way of running my code on a device (starting with android, i'll probably do ios on my macbook). The android emulator that came with VS didn't work (something about HAXM) so I installed [VS emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/), I've made a device and it's running on my desktop but I can't build to the damn thing!

There seems to be nothing about linking my VS emulator to VS itself. I opened it up in android studio and that seems my emulator no problems. How can I tell VS to run my project to the VS emulator?

To be clear on my problem:

I have installed VS Emulator for android, I want to run an android project on the emulator. I can launch it (the vs emulator) and have the device running but there is no option in visual studio for me to run the app on my emulator.

Comment: This is strange. I do debug perfectly fine with the VS Emulator.
If you have intel you must enable HAXM (by downloading it from the android sdk manager).

Comment: Before complaining, you really should learn how to make a good enough question. Nobody can see what's exactly the emulator problem you hit, so how come you want an answer?

Comment: I think you should go out to best buy and get an android tablet for $50.

Comment: @LexLi I have installed VS Emulator for android, I want to run an android project on the emulator. I can launch it and have the device running but there is no option in visual studio for me to run the app on my emulator.

Comment: @Bodungus reformat your question to reflect that, not in a comment nobody cares.

Answer (score 0):

Install Emulator from Android SDK Manager if you want run in Android device.Memory space required to install the emulator is more so better you connect real device & run it.

Comment: Installing the android emulators is no use to me, they use HAXM and that conflicts with the VS Emulator for android (using hyper v). Plus the default simulator sucks!